# android bluetooth connection fail (isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect two mobile phone (galaxy note1, galaxy note2) with bluetooth but socket connection is fail.

this is my LogCat:

```
 I/BluetoothService(24036): BEGIN mConnectThread
 D/BluetoothUtils(24036): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
 D/BluetoothService(24036): setState() 2 -> 1
 D/BluetoothService(24036): Connect Fail
 D/BluetoothService(24036): start
 V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(24036): abortNative
 V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(24036): ...asocket_abort(56) complete
 V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(24036): destroyNative
 V/BluetoothSocket.cpp(24036): ...asocket_destroy(56) complete
 D/BluetoothUtils(24036): isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
 D/BluetoothService(24036): setState() 1 -> 1
 D/BluetoothService(24036): Connect Fail
 D/BluetoothService(24036): start
```

I don't know why 'connect fail' is occured.

isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null' is problem? OR bluetooth uuid is not correct?

Could you tell me what is the problem and how to solve this?

And I also add my src code about bluetoothservice part

```
public class BluetoothService {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothService";

// Intent request code
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

// RFCOMM Protocol
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID
        .fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

private Activity mActivity;
private Handler mHandler;

private ConnectThread mConnectThread; 
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread; 

private int mState;

private static final int STATE_NONE = 0; // we're doing nothing
private static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1; // now listening for incoming
                                            // connections
private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing
                                                // connection
private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3; // now connected to a remote
                                                // device

// Constructors
public BluetoothService(Activity ac, Handler h) {
    mActivity = ac;
    mHandler = h;

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}

/**
 * Check the Bluetooth support
 * 
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean getDeviceState() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Check the Bluetooth support");

    if (btAdapter == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is not available");

        return false;

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth is available");

        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Check the enabled Bluetooth
 */
public void enableBluetooth() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Check the enabled Bluetooth");

    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth Enable Now");

        // Next Step
        scanDevice();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth Enable Request");

        Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}

/**
 * Available device search
 */
public void scanDevice() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Scan Device");

    Intent serverIntent = new Intent(mActivity, DeviceListActivity.class);
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
}

/**
 * after scanning and get device info
 * 
 * @param data
 */
public void getDeviceInfo(Intent data) {
    // Get the device MAC address
    String address = data.getExtras().getString(
            DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object
    // BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    Log.d(TAG, "Get Device Info \n" + "address : " + address);

    connect(device);
}

private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;
}

public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread == null) {

    } else {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread == null) {

    } else {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
}

public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread == null) {

        } else {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread == null) {

    } else {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);

    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

// ConnectedThread 
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket,
        BluetoothDevice device) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connected");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread == null) {

    } else {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread == null) {

    } else {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

//  thread stop
public synchronized void stop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stop");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

public void write(byte[] out) { // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r; // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    } // Perform the write unsynchronized r.write(out); }
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

private void connectionLost() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

}

private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "Connect Success");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed(); 
            Log.d(TAG, "Connect Fail");

            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                        e2);
            }
            BluetoothService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * 
     * @param buffer
     *            The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

`connect fail`  occurs at connectThread.

Answer (score 5):

Try to get correct UUID by:

```
BluetoothDevice device;
ParcelUuid list[] = device.getUuids();
//use e.g. first list[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deviceUUID  = UUID.fromString(list[0].toString());
try {
    TheSocket = TheDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(deviceUUID);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You can add some comments/description to your answer to make it more clear for other users.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add an explanation.